# Why are "tomorrow" and "morning" the same in German?

Tags: dictionary, homonym

I have encountered the following interesting (at least to me) fact, that in German the words *tomorrow* and *morning* have the same spelling: *Morgen*.
I have three questions here:

1. Do these words have the same meaning or they are just homographs?
2. How one could say *I will do something tomorrow morning?*
3. Why is this so? I mean is it due to some historical fact?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70321/discussion-on-question-by-bogdansikach-why-are-tomorrow-and-morning-the-same).

Comment: Also, German is not the only language that does this; compare Spanish *mañana*. Capital letters are of no help there.

Comment: See also Russian `завтра` (tomorrow) and `завтрак` (breakfast, associated with morning).

Comment: Also in Dutch. We even have the same word for it: *morgen*. If we want to say *tomorrow morning*, we say *morgenvroeg* (German: *morgen früh*) and (in Dutch at least) that can even be until noon.

Comment: @dotancohen, I am Russian but I did not notice that. My life will never be the same:)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

First of all, please mind your spelling:

- The **noun** describing the time of the day or the future is capitalized: Der **[Morgen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Morgen_Tageszeit_Masz_Osten)** / das **[Morgen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Morgen_Zukunft)**.
- The **adverb** describing that  something is happening the next day is written in lower case: **[morgen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/morgen)**

Now obviously something can happen in the morning of the next day and *morgen* technically stretches until midnight of the following day. In such cases you add a qualifier and say

> - morgen früh (in the morning) or
> - morgen Vormittag (before noon)

Remember that a most people “start” their new day *in the morning* after a night’s rest. (The concept of a day starting at midnight is a relatively modern one and does not reflect how we humans instinctively perceive our time.) So *der Morgen* (the new day) starts *morgens* (in the morning) - really the same concept.

---

And just for completeness:

Ein [Morgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgen) used to be the area a single worker could till in one Morgen or Vormittag. It’s an unit of measurement which derived its name from the time span.

Comment: I think almost all languages have homographs / homophones that sound odd to the non-natives. It is very nice to see the reason behind it.

Comment: @Mindwin Indeed, why is the past tense of "to read" pronounced like a primary colour?

Comment: @Stephie you mean mind your grammar. Spelling-wise, M is still m whether it is lowercase or uppercase. Grammar covers additional things like capitalization.

Comment: @Stephie your answer is not incorrect, but "der Morgen" and "das Morgen", while for sure connected, are two different nouns. The latter is the nominalized adjective "morgen". So "Es gibt ein Morgen" means "There will be a future", or literally "There will be a tomorrow".

Comment: @thm that’s what I said? Time of day vs. future, first bullet point?

Comment: to make matters more interesting, technically you could also mix it up, for instance like "am morgigen Morgen", though you'd rather find such cases in poems and similar literature forms than everyday speech or formal language.

Comment: Let's not forget the classic German translation of the James Bond movie "Tomorrow never dies" - "Der Morgen stirbt nie" as a cautionary tale.

Comment: How interesting how our conception of time has changed. An ancient Greek time keeping device for law court made season allowances so that periods in winter were shorter than in summer -- there was no abstract duration, perhaps, only division of a day which they knew varied in length.

Answer (score 15):

Probably for the same reason it is in English. "Morrow" is a way of saying morning as is morgen, "tomorrow" is "the morrow" or the morning, and "the morrow" and "der morgen" are pretty much the same idiom.

Old English (and other Germanic) measurements of days centred around when the sun rose and set (and they weren't unique in this, obviously). I don't think anyone can give precise evidence as it'll be lost in the mists of time, but "on or in the next sunrise" is, then, probably a simple and intuitive way of expressing the concept of the next day.

Answer (score 10):

One is a noun "der Morgen", and one is an adverb (*morgen*=tomorrow).

If you want to say "tomorrow morning" you need to say something like

> morgen Vormittag

or possibly (if you mean *early*)

> morgen früh

Although technically *Morgen* is the time between midnight and midday, it's usually used to mean *early* morning

Comment: Specifically, it's usually used for the time after people wake up.

Comment: "Hier spricht Radio Bremen - Beim Gongschlag ist es 16 Uhr, guten Tag, liebe Hörer, guten Morgen liebe Studenten!"

Answer (score 9):

It's not just German. The Spanish word [*mañana*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%B1ana#Spanish) means exactly the same thing.

One way to think of *Morgen* is to say it means *in the morning*. If today’s morning has already passed, why then, obviously it refers to the next day.

Of course, you can always use *Vormittag* which means *before noon*.

Comment: Should that be "mañana"?

Comment: Thank you for the reference to another language. Very useful note.

Comment: Also colloquial Scots: to do something "the morn" is to do it tomorrow.

Comment: You will find examples from many languages. Bulgarian *morning* (noun) is *утро* (utro), *tomorrow* (adverb) is *утре* (utre).

Comment: Also in Afrikaans, which derives from Dutch, we would say Goeie môre, meaning Good morning, or môre meaning tomorrow. Môre oggend can mean tomorrow morning, or you could also say môre voormiddag.

Answer (score 6):

Too add to the [answer that Stephie provided](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40673/why-are-tomorrow-and-morning-the-same-in-german/40675#40675), this pattern is seen in several languages for this same word.

In English `morning` was derived from [`morrow`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/morrow) which has both (*archaic*) meanings of `tomorrow` and `morning`, and is itself related to [`morgen`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Morgen#German).

> **morrow** (*plural* morrows)
>
> 1. (*archaic* or *poetic*) The next or following day.
> 2. (*archaic*) Morning.

The same thing is seen in Spanish with [`mañana`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%B1ana), which again, shares the same meanings of `tomorrow` and `morning`.

> **mañana** *m, f* (*plural* mañanas)
>
> 1. (*feminine*) the morning
> 2. (*masculine*) the near future; tomorrow

Comment: Your link to _morgen_ is somewhat misleading. English _morrow_ does not derive from German _morgen_, but from Old English _morgen_ (which is cognate with German _morgen_, but also not derived from it), which doesn’t have an entry on Wiktionary. You might want to change the link to [Proto-Germanic _*murginaz_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/murginaz), from which both the English and German words derive.

Comment: I changed it to `related` from derived. It was muy original intent, but I hadn't proof-read my answer before posting.

Answer (score 3):

"Morgen", when used to greet someone in the morning, is just short for "Guten Morgen!" which means "good morning". If used to describe the future, like "Morgen wird es regnen", (it will rain tomorrow) it means "tomorrow".

Comment: Unless you say "Am Morgen wird es regnen", which means again in the morning :-)

Comment: . . . while *Morgen wird es regnen* means *tomorrow* it will rain." Gruselig, was?