# Wann wird «das Morgen» statt «der Morgen» benutzt?

Tags: gender

Zitat aus dem Spiegel (Hervorhebung von mir):

> Die Jungen wiederum widersprechen nicht, sie folgen den Alten, sie ertragen Demütigungen, bis sie selbst diejenigen sind, die Befehle erteilen. So ensteht, was die Beduinen »Buschra Chair« nennen, **das bessere Morgen**.

Der Duden gibt fast keine Auskunft darüber, wann man `der/das` Morgen (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Morgen_Zukunft) benutzen sollte.

Comment: Duplikat auf englisch: [Why are “tomorrow” and “morning” the same in German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40673/why-are-tomorrow-and-morning-the-same-in-german/40675#40675).

Comment: Zu den Guillemets: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/please-do-not-edit-swiss-guillemets

Comment: In Österreich gibt es übrigens ein Synonym für »der Morgen«: »Die Früh«. Dieses Nomen wird aber nur in der Wendung *»in der Früh«* (für *»am Morgen«*) verwendet. Siehe: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Früh

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ob Morgen "das" oder "der" ist, hängt von der Bedeutung ab:

- Wird früher Vormittag gemeint, dann ist es "der Morgen".
- Wird die Zukunft gemeint, dann ist es "das Morgen".

Comment: Der Morgen ist etwas anderes als der frühe Vormittag. Morgen: ca 4:00 bis 8:30 Uhr. Früher Vormittag: ca 8:30 bis 10:00 Uhr. Die Grenzen sind natürlich fließend. Zwischen 8 und 9 Uhr gibt es eine Überlappung. Aber um 4:30 Uhr wird niemand von einem frühen Vormittag sprechen, während 9:30 sicher schon zu spät ist um noch vom Morgen zu sprechen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ach, wenn im Duden "früher Vormittag" steht, dann dürfen wir es auch benutzen :)

Answer (score 9):

*Der* Morgen ist der Tagesbeginn.

*Das* Morgen ist dasjenige, was nach dem Heute kommt, das Morgige.

Im Englischen unterscheidet man diese beiden Konzepte durch die Begriffe *the morning* und *the tomorrow* (vgl. [Why are "tomorrow" and "morning" the same in German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40673/25241)).

Answer (score 2):

***Das Morgen*** hat eine Bedeutung:

- Zukunft

  > Das Morgen ist ungeschrieben.
  >   Sie kämpfen für ein gerechteres Morgen.

***Der Morgen*** hat drei Bedeutungen:

- Tageszeit (siehe auch: *morgens*)

  > Der Morgen bricht an.
  >   Ihr seid am Morgen immer schlecht gelaunt.
- Himmelsrichtung (nämlich der Osten; siehe auch: *Morgenland*) [altmodisch]

  > Der Morgen ist unsere Richtung.
  >   Wir müssen gen Morgen fahren.
- Flächenmaß [[die Einheit wird seit etwa 1900 nicht mehr verwendet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgen_(Einheit))]

  > Der Morgen ist verkauft.
  >   Vor uns liegen vier Morgen Wald.

Answer (score 1):

Der Morgen ist ein Nomen (“the morning”)

morgen ist ein Adverb („tomorrow“)

Das Morgen ist ein substantiviertes Adverb (like Shakespeare’s „all our yesterdays“).

Comment: Wobei man nicht vergessen sollte zu erwähnen, dass substantivierte Adverbien gar keine Adverbien sind, sondern astreine und waschechte Substantive. Genau aus diesem Grund werden sie großgeschrieben und können gemeinsam mit Artikeln und Attributen verwendet werden, und unterliegen der Beugung (**des unbekannten Morgens**). Nichts davon ist mit einem Adverb möglich. Ein besserer Name wäre z.B. *»adverbbasiertes Substantiv«.* Sinngemäß dasselbe gilt für alle Substantivierungen (*das Warten* = verbbasiertes Substantiv; *der Große* = adjektivbasiertes Substantiv; usw.)